# No se muestran mapas en app

Tags: android

Tengo un problema. No puedo ver mapas en mi App cuando la publico. Estoy empezando en esto y cuando lo hago con la API Key generada con Debug sin problema, pero cuando utilizo el SHA1 de mi llave con la cual firmo a App no se ven. He leído los temas relacionados y trato de hacer lo indicado pero in éxito. Agradeceré mucho alguna ayuda.

Comment: ¿Tenes la API Key, registrada para "producción"?, osea agregaste la clave SHA1 para registrar en Google Dev que se usara para producción y el nombre de paquete de tu aplicación?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Dmillan, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado, saludos!

Comment: Gracias!!!Llevé a cabo los pasos como viene en un video. generé la API Key primero con: "keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore"  y todo Ok, Después generé la API Key con el SHA1 de mi llave con la cual firmo mi App. Genero la APK la publico y nada. Esta bien? o me falta algo??

Comment: Entiendo que si genero mi API Key de Debug no hay problema, conecto el dispositivo a la PC, lo ejecuto y sin problema. Cuando lo subo a Google Play es cuando viene el problema. Según yo, utilizo un SHA1 diferente para generar una nueva API Key con el mismo nombre del paquete pero con la SHA1 de un archivo jks que generé. Esa es la clave que utilizo para subir la App a producción.

Comment: Error: Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.                                                                                                  Ensure that the following Android Key exists:                                                                                                     API Key: AIzaSyCQq-UYjdypK88npbljEdMJOXQzo9XJPNs. Según yo, hice las cosas bien!!

Comment: Revisa en el administrador si la API esta habilitada. **Trata de agregar esos detalles en tu pregunta, revisar [ask]**.

Comment: Si, la API está habiltada

Comment: @Federico Madoery. Entiendo que si genero mi API Key de Debug no hay problema, conecto el dispositivo a la PC, lo ejecuto y sin problema. Cuando lo subo a Google Play es cuando viene el problema. Según yo, utilizo un SHA1 diferente para generar una nueva API Key con el mismo nombre del paquete pero con la SHA1 de un archivo jks que generé. Esa es la clave que utilizo para subir la App a producción

Comment: @Jorgesys. Entiendo que si genero mi API Key de Debug no hay problema, conecto el dispositivo a la PC, lo ejecuto y sin problema. Cuando lo subo a Google Play es cuando viene el problema. Según yo, utilizo un SHA1 diferente para generar una nueva API Key con el mismo nombre del paquete pero con la SHA1 de un archivo jks que generé. Esa es la clave que utilizo para subir la App a producción. Sigo sin resolverlo

Comment: Nuevamente cambié de Clave pero me sigue enviando el mismo mensaje!!!

Comment: Nuevamente cambié de Clave pero me sigue enviando el mismo mensaje: Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.                                                                                                    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:                                                                                                     API Key: AIzaSyDSsG762D81vJJQSyjaH728kiW2JU-38wE. Qué hago??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Navegando e investigando encontré lo siguiente, lo cual se ve muy parecido a tu problema, ya que mencionas que firmaste y utilizaste el SHA-1 que vos mismo generaste para la API-KEY:

**Información:**

Según la nueva actualización de Play Console cuando firmó su APK con SHA-1 y cargó el APK, solo lo firmó usted, pero según la nueva actualización también está firmado por Google Play para mayor seguridad. Mire aquí parte de la sección de Google Play:

> Con Google Play App Signing: firmas la aplicación con tu clave de subida. A continuación, Google verifica y elimina la firma de clave de subida. Por último, Google vuelve a firmar la aplicación con la clave de firma original que has proporcionado y envía la aplicación al usuario.

[Documentación Oficial](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)

Ahora, la respuesta a te pregunta es "Después de subir con éxito la APK, puedes ver que en la sección, hay dos SHA-1, **la primera SHA-1** es creada por Google y **la segunda SHA-1** es tuya.

Así que solo copia el **Google SHA-1** y pegalo en tu consola donde generas la clave de la API de Google Map.

---

Fuente: [StackOverflow en Ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672565)

Comment: El OP no ha planteado correctamente la pregunta, esto que comentas ya lo realizó. Es importante compartir la información del sitio en español en la cual ya se encuentra este procedimiento.

Comment: Hola @FedericoMadoery,  si, es correcto, sólo utilicé mi SHA1 pero, ¿en donde veo las 2 SHA1 la de Google y la mía? Gracias!!!

Comment: En la [Documentación Oficial](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) -> Aplicaciones que ya están en Google Play - Te da los pasos a seguir. Debería estar en tu [PlayConsole](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/) donde esta tu aplicación subida la deberías encontrar.

Comment: Certificado de firma de aplicaciones

 DESCARGAR CERTIFICADO
Huella digital del certificado MD5 
MD5: 9E:34:CC:A6:07:9F:4E:F8:B9:10:9B:3B:D9:B2:48:B6

Huella digital del certificado SHA‑1 
SHA1: A8:77:B8:21:E2:5B:85:07:35:9C:D4:12:DE:30:79:C8:6C:03:34:D7

Hola Huella digital del certificado SHA‑256 
SHA256: 6D:D8:B5:C7:D8:38:46:B9:CE:57:4B:0B:F3:27:7B:F2:FA:75:24:9F:4D:50:70:2B:C3:ED:EB:2

Comment: Hola @FedericoMadoery este es el SHA1 que encontré de Google: Certificado de firma de aplicaciones

Huella digital del certificado SHA‑1 
SHA1: A8:77:B8:21:E2:5B:85:07:35:9C:D4:12:DE:30:79:C8:6C:03:34:D7

Y este es el mío: Certificado de subida

Huella digital del certificado MD5 
MD5: 77:8B:68:22:7C:76:10:56:50:F4:30:62:1C:85:91:42

Huella digital del certificado SHA‑1 
SHA1: D1:4A:C0:37:BD:F5:56:2F:D0:D5:45:B6:2A:61:59:5D:3C:DF:82:D2

Comment: @FedericoMadoery Ya llevé a cabo lo que me recomendaste, es decir, copio el SHA1 de Google y lo pego en la Clave de API (generé una nueva) y lo guardo. La Clave de API la copio en mi AndroidManifest.xml y en google_maps_api.xml, sincronizo, conecto mi dispositivo y ejecuto la App. Cuando quiero ver el mapa me manda el mensaje: nsure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
API Key: AIzaSyAfiox-ags1i81MzDaQrBxGTOYr9mD2l3s. No sé que pasa!!!

Comment: Tenes las dos SHA-1 Agregadas?  El nombre del Paquete Correcto en ambas? Habilitada para Android? De ahí en adelante me funciono, no estaría viendo el error.

Comment: @FedericoMadoery mi estimado!!! Muchas gracias!!! Ese era el problema. ya quedó!!! Agradezco mucho la ayuda!!!! Saludos!!!!

Comment: @Jorgesys, Hola, Muchas gracias!!! Ese era el problema. ya quedó!!! Agradezco mucho la ayuda!!!! Saludos!!!!